# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties" when using BitPay and Spree Commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

When I try to

```
bundle install
```

I get the error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    spree_bitpay (>= 0) ruby depends on
      spree_auth_devise (>= 0) ruby depends on
        devise (~> 2.0.4) ruby depends on
          railties (~> 3.1) ruby

    spree_bitpay (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rails (= 4.0.9) ruby depends on
        railties (4.0.9)
```

I have tried 2 versions of my Gemfile, one where I have the standard Gemfile plus the bitpay line, and one where I have all other gems commented out, and just the bitpay line, neither work.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.9'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'spree_bitpay', :git => 'https://github.com/bitpay/spree-bitpay.git'
```

I'm new to Ruby, and Gemfiles etc. Thanks =)

Doing 'gem list' I can see that I have both required versions:
railties (4.1.8, 4.0.12, 4.0.9, 3.1.0)

Comment: remove version requiring in `Gemfile` leave just `gem 'rails'` and run `bundle install` again

Comment: Error still reads:Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties": In Gemfile: spree_bitpay (>= 0) ruby depends on spree_auth_devise (>= 0) ruby depends on devise (~> 2.0.4) ruby depends on railties (~> 3.1) ruby spree_bitpay (>= 0) ruby depends on rails (= 4.0.9) ruby depends on railties (4.0.9)

Comment: Have you already tried running `bundle update`?

Comment: Yes: bundle update Updating https://github.com/bitpay/spree-bitpay.git Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/......... Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/.. Resolving dependencies... Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties": In Gemfile: spree_bitpay (>= 0) ruby depends on spree_auth_devise (>= 0) ruby depends on devise (~> 2.0.4) ruby depends on railties (~> 3.1) ruby spree_bitpay (>= 0) ruby depends on rails (= 4.0.9) ruby depends on railties (4.0.9)

Comment: spree_bitpay depend on rails 3.1 - 3.2. You can't use rails 4.x for now.

Comment: I tried using rails 3.2 as you suggested, but that doesn't seem to be the case: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails": In Gemfile: spree_bitpay (>= 0) ruby depends on rails (= 4.0.9) ruby rails (3.2.0)

Comment: spree_bitpay v 1.0.2 actually has a hard requirement for rails 4.0.9 and spree 2.2 for right now. I suspect that the problem is associated with the spree_auth_devise requirement as suggested below. Have a look at the Gemfile here https://github.com/philosodad/spree-bitpay-example-store

Answer (score 0):

The problem exists because spree-bitpay's gemspec only specifies 'spree_auth_devise', while the version that they're specifying in their [Gemfile](https://github.com/bitpay/spree-bitpay/blob/master/Gemfile) is actually as such:

```
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git', :branch => '2-2-stable'
```

I suspect that when you `bundle install`, it's attempting to use the Rubygems.org version of spree_auth_devise, which has not been updated since 2012 (seems to be around the time of Rails 3).

The solution to your problem is to add to your Gemfile the above line.

Furthermore, you should bring up this issue with the maintainers of spree-bitpay. Please open an issue with them, I'm sure they'll appreciate it!

Comment: Indeed, we would appreciate it.